# Food menu slider with an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, menu, slider, infinite

could you please help me to understand how to make slider I see in "our menu" section of https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61177_v1/#undefined6 site with an infinite loop and same functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact slider you are looking for is a [Slick Auto play slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which is just the auto play version of the example you have. Example code.

```
    $('.autoplay').slick({
  slidesToShow: 5, //The amount of slides to be in view at any given time
  slidesToScroll: 1, // The amount of slides to scroll on click or auto scoll
  autoplay: true, // Sets the slider to automatically slide through the slides
  autoplaySpeed: 2000, // The interval between sliding between slides
});
```

Example image of slider on slicks website:

[image]